# data Binding with Nativescript

Tags: angular, data-binding, nativescript, angular2-forms

I'm starting a project with Nativescript and I'm trying to make a page to create the user. This is my **create.user.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

import firebase = require('nativescript-plugin-firebase');

@Component({
    selector:'create-user',
    template:`
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label class="titulo" text="Create User"></Label>
                    <TextField hint="Email" keyboardType="text" [(ngModel)]="email"
                        autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                    <TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="password"
                        autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                    <Button class="submit-botton" (tap)="create()" text="Crear usuario"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
        `,
    styleUrls:['login/login.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent{

    email:string;
    password:string;

    constructor(private routerExt: RouterExtensions ){}

        create(){
            firebase.createUser({
                email:this.email,
                password: this.password

            }).then(
                (result)=>{

                    this.routerExt.navigate(["/chatListado"],{
                        transition:{
                            name: "flip",
                            duration:500,
                            curve:"linear"
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("User Created");
                },
                (errorMessage)=>{
                    alert('error: ' + errorMessage);
                }
            );

        }
}
```

At the beginning when I tap the button to create it, it returns undefined. I couldn't get the email and the password and after searching I observed that I needed to import the NativeScriptFormsModule in my app.module.ts so I made it.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

//use the data binding
import { NativeScriptFormsModule} from "nativescript-angular/forms"

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app.routing";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

//login
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { Login} from './login/login';
import { CreateUserComponent } from './login/create.user.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        CreateUserComponent

    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With this theoretically it should work but now when I start the app I get this error on my console:

> JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for
>   form control with unspecified name attribute JS: Error: No value
>   accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute JS:     at
>   _throwError (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1838:11)
>   [angular] JS:     at setUpControl
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1751:9)
>   [angular] JS:     at NgModel._setUpStandalone
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4320:9)
>   [angular] JS:     at NgModel._setUpControl
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4306:37)
>   [angular] JS:     at NgModel.ngOnChanges
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4237:18)
>   [angular] JS:     at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10715:19)
>   [angular] JS:     at checkAndUpdateNodeInline
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12097:17)
>   [angular] JS:     at checkAndUpdateNode
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12065:16)
>   [angular] JS:     at debugCheckAndUpdateNode
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12694:59)
>   [angular] JS:     at debugCheckDirectivesFn
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12635:13)
>   [angular] JS:     at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
>   (ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.ngfactory.js:363:5) [angular] JS:
>   at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12620:21)
>   [angular] JS:     at checkAndUpdateView
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12032:14)
>   [angular] JS:     at callViewAction
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12347:17)
>   [angular]

And now I can not go to the page to create the user...

Someone knows what is happening here? If I'm missing something or something like that?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: What version of angular and nativescript are you using?

Comment: In my package.json I see that the version of nativescript is 2.4.2 and the nativescript-angular is the 1.2.0

Comment: angular version 2.x or 4.x ? can you try to remove node_module platforms, run npm install then run the application

Comment: doesn't work for that :S
The version of angular is the 4.0.0